# R multcomp: extract cld output

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I built a linear mixed model to analyse my data and used the package `multcomp` for pairwise comparisons. I already created a ggplot with the model output and I'd like to **put the `cld()` output (letters) above the bars**.

But I have no idea how to extract the letters from the `cld()` output. It is a list of 10, containing many objects and vectors and frankly I don't fully understand half of them (moreover, I have little experience with lists though I read about them several times and did many basic exercises, I still find it difficult to grasp).

When you run `cld()` in R, it shows you exactly what you need in the console, and that's what I'd like to extract. My internet searches did not produce any solution so far.

## code

```
# packages
library(lme4)
library(multcomp)
library(ggplot2)

# dummy dataset
treatment <- c(rep("X",4),rep("Y",4),rep("Z",4))
replicate <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"),3)
Y <- c(18.853,20.165,20.120,21.000,18.772,19.825,20.874,19.001,22.007,21.875,21.235,21.904)
data <- data.frame(treatment,replicate,Y)

# model
lm1 <- lmer(Y ~ treatment + (1|replicate), data=data)
drop1(lm1, test="Chisq")

# pairwise comparison
pc1 <- glht(lm1, mcp(treatment = "Tukey"))
summary(pc1)
cld(pc1, level=0.05) # how to extract this result?

# parameter estimates
lm1.e <- lmer(Y ~ treatment -1 + (1|replicate), data=data)

# plotfile
pfile <- data.frame(treatment=c("X","Y","Z"))
pfile$Y <- fixef(lm1.e)
pfile$SE <- summary(lm1.e)$coefficients[,2]
pfile$minSE <- pfile$Y-pfile$SE
pfile$maxSE <- pfile$Y+pfile$SE

# plot
ggplot(pfile, aes(treatment, Y)) + # how to add cld() result above bars?
  xlab("Treatment") +
  ylab(expression(paste("Y (g)", sep=""))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color="black", fill="white") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=minSE, ymax=maxSE), width=.2, position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

Comment: `cld(pc1, level=0.05)$mcletters$Letters` seems to contain the information you want.

Comment: Which you can find out by studying the code of `multcomp::print.cld`.

Comment: Ah yes, I can extract it that way, thank you!
The second line returns an error for me:
`Error: 'print.cld' is not an exported object from 'namespace:multcomp'`

Comment: If you use three colons instead (`multcomp:::print.cld`) it will print the code, where you'll see that it basically calls: `print(x$mcletters$Letters)`

Comment: @bobbel, post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `multcomp:::print.cld` you can see the code, where you'll see that it basically calls: `print(x$mcletters$Letters)`